# "Object required" Error when Calling Internal Methods

Tags: .net, winforms, vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to call an internal method from QTP on one of my .NET objects. When I run the script however I get an "Object required" error message.

Here is my script:

```
Set gridObj = SwfWindow("Test Program").SwfObject("dataGrid").Object
Set dataRow = gridObj.RowIndexToDataRow(0).Object
Msgbox dataRow.Item(0)
```

The `RowIndexToDataRow(0)` method is pretty simple, it takes an integer as an argument and returns a `DataRow` object.

The script is failing on the 2nd line of code with this error message:

> Object required: 'gridObj.RowIndexToDataRow(...)'
>
> Line (2): "Set dataRow = gridObj.RowIndexToDataRow(0).Object".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `WScript.Echo TypeName(gridObj)`?

Comment: I get the error message `Object required: 'WScript'`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you're using QTP. Try `MsgBox TypeName(gridObj)` instead.

Comment: I got this: http://i.imgur.com/DyqqZ92.png

Comment: Does the grid contain any rows that `RowIndexToDataRow()` could return? (`MsgBox gridObj.Items.Count`)

Comment: The gridObj doesn't have an Items property, instead I tried `MsgBox gridObj.RowCount` and it returned `13`

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry. I'm not really familiar with QTP or Windows forms.

Comment: RowIndexToDataRow returns something that is not a valid object for VBSH. What does it return? Maybe an integer? Everything is possible in a WinForms datagrid. Try evaluating it in the watch window, you will see if it is an object or a simple type or a variant or whatever.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Looking at the source code for RowIndexToDataRow it has its return type set to `DataRow` is this what you mean?

Comment: @StickFigs. Yeah. I am not sure if QTP is supposed to be able to dereference such "pointer" (object references). This is not COM/DCOM, is it?

Comment: Please show us the source of the RowIndexToDataRow method (.net side, of course), at least the header (signature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working in the end:

```
Set gridObj = SwfWindow("Test Program").SwfObject("dataGrid").Object
Msgbox gridObj.Item(0,0).CellValue
```

Another discovery was that apparently when setting a variable if you use `Set blahblah` it is expecting `blahblah` to be set to an Object. So if you are calling on a function like `Set blahblah = gridObj.getSize()` where it will return an `int` it will complain about "Object required". This can be fixed by using `blahblah = gridObj.getSize()` without the `Set`.

Comment: +1 for sharing this insight to everybody. And you are right, using Set implies the source is any object. If it is not, you get the error you mentioned. But now I am still wondering what 'RowIndexToDataRow(0).Object' really returned...Empty/Nothing? An integer?